# Movement energy of object is a warping spacetime - good example?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, mass-energy

Suppose we have two objects with little mass. These objects move at high speed and parallel to each other. And very close to each other.
As a consequence of relativity when an object increases its speed its energy rises. In some sense, this energy gets converted to relativistic mass. More mass warps more spacetime. Because the objects are very close to each other, gravity starts working and these objects begin to attract yourself to yourself.

```
-->---O----->--O--- 
                 ----O---> ___OO__\
                 ----O--->        /
-->---O----->--O---
```

It is a correct example of how energy (like mass) warps spacetime?

What is my intention? We know that massive objects warp spacetime and slow time. But speed movement also does this even it has less mass until is not moved.

Answer (score 0):

The situation is the same as thinking of the 2 masses at rest, and another frame at high speed measuring the gravitational field.

In the frame of the 2 masses, the field can be taken as the Newtonian with very good precision, supposing the density is not too high.

In the moving frame at relativistic speed, the metric and the geodesics must be corrected by GR.

Comment: I know it's not easy to reconstruct this situation. I want to know is this situation theoretically is possible according with general relativity?